# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

Tags: bash, syntax

I get this error

```
(-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&' )
```

when I run the command below:

```
sudochown -hRfwebadmin:www-data /web/<repertoire>&&sudoln -s /web/<repertoire>
/var/www/html/<repertoire>&&sudochown -hRfwebadmin:www-data
/var/www/html/<repertoire>&&sudols -al /var/www/html/
```

so can someone help what's wrong in the syntax of this command line

Comment: There's quite a bit wrong with that command. It's missing spaces, it contains generic placeholders, and it makes no sense.

Comment: can you recommend the correct one:
sudo chown -hRfwebadmin:www-data /web/<repertoire>&&sudo ln -s /web/<repertoire>
/var/www/html/<repertoire>&&sudo chown -hRfwebadmin:www-data
/var/www/html/<repertoire>&&sudo ls -al /var/www/html/

Comment: Not unless you provide us with what you are trying to do and where you got that command.

Comment: @Zacharee
it is in order to make available a site on the server after uploading it in the /web/ rep,
but only the /var/www/html is used to point to this /web for security purpose. so the /var/www/html will link to /web

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what `<repertoire>` is supposed to be. Is that the name of a directory? The `<` and `>` symbols have special meanings in the shell so their presence makes your command very hard to understand. When asking a question, you need to explain what you are trying to do. Since your command is very wrong, it is very hard to guess what you meant to say if you don't actually tell us.

Answer (score 6):

I *think* what you are trying to do is run these commands:

```
sudo chown -hRf webadmin:www-data /web/repertoire &&
sudo ln -s /web/repertoire /var/www/html/repertoire &&
sudo chown -hRf webadmin:www-data /var/www/html/repertoire &&
sudo ls -al /var/www/html/
```

The `&&` means "run the next command only if the previous one was successful". It isn't actually needed as such. Also, the second `chown` command is pointless. The directory `/var/www/html/repertoire` is a link to `/web/repertoire` and since you have already changed the ownerhip of the target, there's no point in changing it for the link as well. It has already been changed (that's the point of a link). So, what you really wanted to do is:

```
sudo chown -hRf webadmin:www-data /web/repertoire 
sudo ln -s /web/repertoire /var/www/html/repertoire
sudo ls -al /var/www/html/
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation, i opted for your recommendation:
sudo chown -hRf webadmin:www-data /web/repertoire &&
sudo ln -s /web/repertoire /var/www/html/repertoire &&
sudo chown -hRf webadmin:www-data /var/www/html/repertoire &&
sudo ls -al /var/www/html/
no error anymore, will test the result.
thanks

Comment: @tsilokomail What you really want is the second piece of code because the second `chown` is redundant.

Comment: @tsilokomail If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.